# Displaying MS-Office documents and spreadsheets inline in a J2EE application

Tags: java, ms-word, inline

What's the best way to do this? Essentially, I want to be able to display text files and other MS-Office documents inline and allow the user to provide comments in context (not in the document but as "metadata" around the document).

Answer (score 0):

There are many versions of the MS formats. So one would probably need to convert all of them to the same formats. Then having a zip with a Content.xml, you can translate it in you own XHTML format. And you can at least can display a simple-styled content.

```
MS docs -[converter]-> single format -[XSLT+java]-> prepared HTML -[web app]->
```